# how to redirect page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i have 4 images and then i have applied automatic swiping,It's working nice,but now i have added text (skip) on Image when i click  on Skip,text is Redirected to another page(text.html)
My Problem is When i Click Skip it's Redirected page(text.html) but page css not applied. 
But with out click on skip with automatic sliding redirected page(text.html) is fine.

```
  <div id="container">
      <img src="../images/4 copy.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
      <div class="caption"><font color="white" >fourth Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="../html/text.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

when click skip it's redirect to text.html but text.html css not applied total page will changed 
when call direct text.html it's displayed nice css also applied
can you please  tell me how to make css apply to text.html when i click skip.
Thanks in Advanced

Text.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
            <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


                <style>
                    .ui-page {
                        background-color: #666 !important;
                    }
                    .ui-content {
                        background: transparent url(http://brandthunder.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Mac_Desktop_Background.jpg);
                        background-size : 100% 100%;
                        color:#FFFFFF;
                        text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
                    }
                    .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
                        display:none;
                    }
                    #one
                    {
                        padding : 0;
                        margin : 0;
                    }
                    #two
                    {
                        padding : 0;
                        margin : 0;
                    }
                    #four
                    {
                        padding-top :1%;
                        margin : 0;
                    }
                </style>

                <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

                    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();

                    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();

                    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

                    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

                    $(".ui-content").height(content);


                    });//]]>  

                    </script>


                </head>
                <body>
                    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="p1">
                        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" id="header" style="background:#808080;">
                            <h1>User guide</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="content"  class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="background: #666;color:white;font-family:sans-serif">
                            <p id="one">Step 1:</p>
                            <p id="two">Fill in your Details to Get Started </p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="content" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="background: #666;color:white;font-family:sans-serif">
                            <p id="one">Step 2:</p>
                            <p id="two">Browse the application</p>
                            <p id="four"><font color="green">Save with Lighting</font></p>
                            <p> in your Deatails to Get Started </br>
                            Fill in your Deatails to Get Started </p>
                            <h5><font color="green">Explore light options</font></h5>
                            <p>Fill in your Deatails to Get Started </br>
                            Fill in your Deatails to Get Started </p>

                        </div>



                        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" id="footer" style="background:#808080;">
                            <ul data-role="listview" >
                                <!-- <li style="text-align:center;">Save with lighting</li> -->
                                <li style="background:#808080;"><a href="" style="text-align:center;background-color: #666;"></h3>good day</h3></a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>  


                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: you need to add your javascript code as well.

Comment: css on text.html included by files?

Comment: sounds like text.html doesn't include your css...

Comment: @deadulya now i added  the Text.html please give me any idea about my problem

Comment: @user3616693 it looks like included files are not loading, use FireBug or similar instrument to check if all files on page loaded. P.S. In firebug it on tab "Network"

Comment: @deadulya file loading but page alignment different when i click skip

Answer (score -2, accepted):

with jQuery you can define class on which you can perform an on-click event

like

```
$( ".skipclass" ).on( "click", function() {
  // do something here like
  // window.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';
  // or ajax request
});
```

further info http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: thanks for reply i know you code will work but please lock my code 
 <div class="caption"><font color="white" >fourth Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="../html/text.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a> i want when click skip it's redirect to Text.html with css

Comment: with my code you may try to mod your <span class="one"> to <span class="one skipclass">

Answer (score 3):

This is a common jQuery Mobile misconception.

You need to learn how jQuery Mobile handles pages. Only initial HTML file is fully loaded into the DOM. Every other HTML page is only partially loaded, basically lets say we have 2 HTML files, one is called **index.html** and second one is called **second.html**.

When jQuery Mobile app is initialized, framework will load **index.html** into the DOM.
When you go to other page, in our case **second.html**, only **data-role="page"** container div is going to be loaded into the **DOM**, everything else is discarded.

This is because jQuery Mobile used AJAX for page handling. If first file is already inside the DOM, there's no reason in loading HEAD content of other HTML files.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)**.

In your case just move your <style></style> to a **data-role="page"** container div.

Basically do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>        
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

                    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();

                    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();

                    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

                    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

                    $(".ui-content").height(content);


                    });//]]>  

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="p1">
            <style>
            .ui-page {
                background-color: #666 !important;
            }
            .ui-content {
                background: transparent url(http://brandthunder.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Mac_Desktop_Background.jpg);
                background-size : 100% 100%;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
            }
            .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
                display:none;
            }
            #one
            {
                padding : 0;
                margin : 0;
            }
            #two
            {
                padding : 0;
                margin : 0;
            }
            #four
            {
                padding-top :1%;
                margin : 0;
            }
            </style>            
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" id="header" style="background:#808080;">
                <h1>User guide</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content"  class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="background: #666;color:white;font-family:sans-serif">
                <p id="one">Step 1:</p>
                <p id="two">Fill in your Details to Get Started </p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="background: #666;color:white;font-family:sans-serif">
                <p id="one">Step 2:</p>
                <p id="two">Browse the application</p>
                <p id="four"><font color="green">Save with Lighting</font></p>
                <p> in your Deatails to Get Started <br/>
                    Fill in your Deatails to Get Started </p>
                <h5><font color="green">Explore light options</font></h5>
                <p>Fill in your Deatails to Get Started <br/>
                    Fill in your Deatails to Get Started </p>

            </div>



            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" id="footer" style="background:#808080;">
                <ul data-role="listview" >
                    <!-- <li style="text-align:center;">Save with lighting</li> -->
                    <li style="background:#808080;"><a href="" style="text-align:center;background-color: #666;"><h3>good day</h3></a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for js try

`document.location = url`